# json Problems to echo, arrays

Tags: php, json

I am working on a script, that will use steam api, and i selected to use json for the response format.
So i have used var_dump with and without jason_decode() and it appears to be ok.
But can't manage to print it out, or echo it.

Script that gets the json data

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['SteamId'];
$get = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=API_KEY_REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY&steamids=$id",true);
$data = json_decode($get);
//var_dump($data);
echo $data->realname;
?>
```

So, that i get using the var_dump with json_decode is this.

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["response"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["players"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (15) { ["steamid"]=> string(17) "76561198053511970" ["communityvisibilitystate"]=> int(3) ["profilestate"]=> int(1) ["personaname"]=> string(9) "Undefined" ["lastlogoff"]=> int(1340978067) ["profileurl"]=> string(41) "http://steamcommunity.com/id/Heisteknikk/" ["avatar"]=> string(114) "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/5c/5c75278da69102d9c8290bccd1becbb4081954cd.jpg" ["avatarmedium"]=> string(121) "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/5c/5c75278da69102d9c8290bccd1becbb4081954cd_medium.jpg" ["avatarfull"]=> string(119) "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/5c/5c75278da69102d9c8290bccd1becbb4081954cd_full.jpg" ["personastate"]=> int(1) ["realname"]=> string(7) "Andreas" ["primaryclanid"]=> string(18) "103582791430704052" ["timecreated"]=> int(1322427688) ["loccountrycode"]=> string(2) "NO" ["locstatecode"]=> string(2) "09" } } } }
```

And the raw data from the json.

```
{
    "response": {
        "players": [
            {
                "steamid": "76561198053511970",
                "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
                "profilestate": 1,
                "personaname": "Undefined",
                "lastlogoff": 1340978067,
                "profileurl": "http:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/id\/Heisteknikk\/",
                "avatar": "http:\/\/media.steampowered.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/avatars\/5c\/5c75278da69102d9c8290bccd1becbb4081954cd.jpg",
                "avatarmedium": "http:\/\/media.steampowered.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/avatars\/5c\/5c75278da69102d9c8290bccd1becbb4081954cd_medium.jpg",
                "avatarfull": "http:\/\/media.steampowered.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/avatars\/5c\/5c75278da69102d9c8290bccd1becbb4081954cd_full.jpg",
                "personastate": 1,
                "realname": "Andreas",
                "primaryclanid": "103582791430704052",
                "timecreated": 1322427688,
                "loccountrycode": "NO",
                "locstatecode": "09"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

I've been searching around on google about printing the json using "echo $data->realname;".
So i don't know what i did wrong, so it canno't echo the data.

Comment: $data->response->players[0]->realname

Comment: @kingcoyote That worked well, I am not familar using json, so that was a grat help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Intro

Hey there, this is a REALLY old question, but since there's no answer here.

You do have it right when it comes to decoding the `JSON` PHP has the built-in function `json_decode` which can easily decode the function for you:

```
$json = '{...}';
$obj = json_decode($json, [ASSOC_ARRAY = FALSE]);
```

The second Param you can set to bool for an associative array which would change mentions from:

```
$obj->response;
```

To

```
$obj['response'];
```

---

## Response

Now you say you need the `realname` from the players, that would be as simple as getting it via the player's position in the array, or just looping through the array:

```
echo $obj->response->players[0]->realname; // Andreas
```

Or if you have multiple users:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($obj->response->players); $i++ ) {
  echo $obj->response->players[$i]->realname;
}
```

Which would display all of the `realname`(s)